# Why does Mercurial's strip command not rewrite history?

Tags: mercurial

The Mercurial help text says, that the "strip command removes the specified changesets and all their descendants." This sounds very much like rewriting history to me, and that it must cause problems if somebody has based his work on one of the changesets that suddenly is removed. But the help text also says that the command "is not a history-rewriting operation and can be used on changesets in the public phase." I am sure that the person who wrote the help text knew very well what he was doing, so what am I missing to understand this?

Answer (score 8):

The key point is that if you strip a public changeset, and then pull it again from somewhere, you haven't caused any issues. You just get the original changeset back.

If you (for example) collapse two public changesets together, and then pull the original from somewhere, you now have two branches. One with the original two changesets, and one with the collapsed changeset, but both have the same changes. At that point hell breaks loose and child eating monsters roam the earth.

Hence 'history re-writing' isn't the same as 'history stripping'.

---

[davidmc24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021250/davidmc24) pointed out [this post](http://markmail.org/message/ca7gwolevyjeau74) by Matt Mackall (Mercurial's father) in which he says basically the same thing

Comment: I love the child eating monsters.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say it with certainty, but my guess is that it's "grandfathered in". `hg strip` started out as part of `mq` which predates the addition of *phases* by at least three years.

Likely better phrasing would be:

> is not *considered *a history-rewriting operation and can be used on changesets in the public phase

When phases were added a huge amount of care was taken to break no one's existing workflow.  Commits start out in the *draft* phase and become *public* once pushed.  Any phase-aware commands knows that after pushing the commit's phase is *public* and not to allow modification if it (unless the push was to a non-publishing repository...).

However, there were people already using `strip` manually and in scripts to remove changesets that had been pushed, and if `strip` had after an upgrade suddenly said "Hey, you can't strip that it's public!" then those people would have had their backward-compatibility promise broken.

Phases is slowly growing into a pretty amazing [evolve](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution) system that will be a much better choice than mq for almost all cases, but I still doubt we'll ever get Matt to remove mq and strip -- he still insists on maintaining a Python 2.4 compatible codebase and that's 9 years old!

Tl;Dr: Even though `strip` was always a disabled extension, too many people use it to change it's behavior w/ the advent of phases.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an. I appreciate the correction and the explanation.

Comment: Does this mean that `strip` doesn't _remove_ the changsets but just _hides_ them? I was looking for a way to 100% _remove_ minor commits from developing before publishing. This is safe and a very important feature, because as a developer you should make local commits often (this is one of the advantages of a DVCS, isn't it?), and merge a "one commit per feature" changeset into the master branch (this is how all master branches look like, e.g. the ones from Python, Sphinx ect.). Is there any way I can achieve that in a clear way with Mercurial using "Phases"?

Comment: Strip **removes** them.  My point was that it does so outside of the confines of the phases system because it predates it by 3 years.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So you think using ``strip`` is fine, but it would be better if it additionally made use of phases.

Comment: As per this discussion on the mercurial-devel mailing list, I believe this is the incorrect interpretation.  http://markmail.org/message/ca7gwolevyjeau74

Comment: @Iodnas stripping in order to publish is **not** a good idea! You discard important details that you'll need as a developer. To push one commit per feature, develop in a feature branch, merge it to `default`, and just push `default`: A single changeset will be pushed (the merge changeset), containing all changes in the branch.

Comment: @davidmc24 that's a good find, but I suspect it's a post-discovery rationalization.  Matt was never going to let the new feature (phases) alter the behavior of an old one.

Comment: @alexis you're mistaken.  If you develop in a branch, merge to default and then push you'll push the merge changeset _and_ all the changesets that were created in the branch.  A changeset cannot be exist in a repository w/o _all_ of it's ancestors there too, and that includes those in the other other branch.

Comment: Oops, right! Sorry for the misdirection. I do a lot of selective pushing but the merges are in the other direction: I merge from default into a local named branch that _doesn't_ get pushed. Still, stripping good changesets is a terrible idea. Grafting + bookmarking is probably the right tool for controlling visibility, no?

Comment: @Ry4an Sadly, the [Mercurial Glossary](http://selenic.com/hg/help/glossary) doesn't help clear up this nuance of the original meaning.  I think it was intended to mean "writing a modified version of pre-existing history", but I can't find a source to back that up.  "History, rewriting": The changesets in a repository are immutable. However, extensions to Mercurial can be used to alter the repository, usually in such a way as to preserve changeset contents.

Comment: @davidmc24 yeah, as long as we've all come to understand what it doesn't does I'm happy to call it rewriting or not.